# Resolving module not found with Webpack (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in )

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, node-modules

I have a package A which has dependency on say, axios. Package A builds independently and works fine. However, when I try to consume package A as a dependency in package B and try to compile, I am facing issue as below:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/A/dist/impl/lifecycle-associate-tool-client-impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/workplace/LifeCycle/src/B/node_modules/A/dist/impl'
 @ ./node_modules/A/dist/impl/lifecycle-associate-tool-client-impl.js 17:32-48
 @ ./node_modules/A/dist/lifecycle-client-factory.js
 @ ./node_modules/A/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/api-clients/lifecycles/lifecycles.module.ts
 @ ./src/application.ts
```

In node_modules folder at the src level of package B, I have package A and inside of package A's node_modules, I have axios.

What I am aware of is that NPM resolves dependencies by looking at node_modules directory and then looking at parent if not found. But how to resolve this inward dependency situation?

Could webpack help to resolve the axios dependency by providing path in the resolve module to look axios in the node_modules, like below?

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src"),
    },
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "..", 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"],
  }
```

I don't want to specify axios as dependency in package.json of package B.

Comment: Are you sure that package A has package axios as dependency and that it's not an error on package A forgetting to add axios as a dependency there?

Comment: It clearly says that axios is not present.

Comment: Please check the package.json in the node_modules

Comment: To be clear, above error only happens while building package B. I can assure that Package A's package.json has axios as dependency and it builds just fine on its own.